# Why is my session still alive

Tags: spring, spring-security, redis

I am using spring with redis backed sessions.
If I access the site, I see that sessions is added to database.
Then I run `flushdb` on the database.
Then I try and access the site, and sessions is still alive (I have the same session id.)  The redis keys are different, but the session id's are the same.
Is the session being stored somewhere else not in redis?  Is this expected?

Using windows 64 bit redis 2.8.2400.

some pom dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 <!--  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Relavent Beans

```
<beans:bean id="RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" 
    class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" />
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:port="6379" />
```

some web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.mysite.listeners.sessionStarted</listener-class>
    </listener>

<filter>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Controller function for closing session

```
RequestMapping(value = "/closeSession", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String closeSession(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.info("Closeing Session (greri002 for testing).");
        session.invalidate();
        //request.logout();
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
        return "OK";
    }
```

Comment: are you using spring security?  what server are you using?

Comment: imo - java config is much nicer and the xml config for spring.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security is managing your sessions storing the data in redis.  You only need to bring in something like redis if you're planning on being able to share session data between nodes.

Spring's SecurityContext where security info in stored.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html

Assuming you're using a server that supports 3.0 Servlets you just need to call logout() on a HttpServletRequest object.  A spring MVC sample -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/me/logout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    request.logout();
    return "OK";
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.1.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#servletapi-logout

If you don't have access to HttpServletRequest you can do

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

Also make sure you have logout for the http config config'ed correctly.  he's mine

```
    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout"
                delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,jsessionid"
                invalidate-session="true"
                success-handler-ref="myLogoutFilter"/>
```

Comment: I have a /closeSession map which calls `session.invalidate();`   Why doesn't that work either?

Comment: I've tried it, but it didn't work, appending code to post.

Comment: i'm using request.logout() with a spring4 and tomcat8.  your app server needs to support Servlet 3.0

Comment: The setAuth(null) does work, actually, it's just that the listener which should be triggered when a new session is created is not fired, this causes a variable to be set on the session to tell me that it is a new session and force logic to happen.  Do you know why this listener isn't being triggered, it does trigger when a user first comes to the site.

Comment: The closeSession does remove it from redis, but actually, my session id still doesn't go away, it still persisting, thats why the listener isn't being triggered.

Comment: listeners for security is normally set in your spring security config.  you could have entry-point or custom-filter set.  hard to say without seeing the config

Comment: I've narrowed it down farther, I see now that the jsessionid is not changing, but the RedisSessionid is being removed and a new one is being added.

Comment: spring security doesn't manage the cookie.  the cookie is handled by your serlvet container.